# pip install gives ResolutionImpossible: the user requested flax 0.6.8 but t5x depends on flax 0.6.8

Tags: python, pip, dependency-management, flax

I am trying to a requirements file that depends on versions of the packages `flax` and `t5x` at specific commits.

The problem can be reproduced with the following command:

```
pip install "flax @ git+https://github.com/google/flax@ccf48a62acafd1f8658d60e21457c4bb57b25b95" "t5x @ git+https://github.com/google-research/t5x.git@24feab6892a79b3fc465b7b3f2d1c77fc437b67a" jestimator clu orbax
```

This gives the following output:

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
Collecting flax@ git+https://github.com/google/flax@ccf48a62acafd1f8658d60e21457c4bb57b25b95
  Cloning https://github.com/google/flax (to revision ccf48a62acafd1f8658d60e21457c4bb57b25b95) to /tmp/pip-install-wh571lzf/flax_b627060d1d0a434bb44bed9c11cff293
  Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/google/flax /tmp/pip-install-wh571lzf/flax_b627060d1d0a434bb44bed9c11cff293
  Running command git rev-parse -q --verify 'sha^ccf48a62acafd1f8658d60e21457c4bb57b25b95'
  Running command git fetch -q https://github.com/google/flax ccf48a62acafd1f8658d60e21457c4bb57b25b95
  Running command git checkout -q ccf48a62acafd1f8658d60e21457c4bb57b25b95
  Resolved https://github.com/google/flax to commit ccf48a62acafd1f8658d60e21457c4bb57b25b95
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting t5x@ git+https://github.com/google-research/t5x.git@24feab6892a79b3fc465b7b3f2d1c77fc437b67a
  Cloning https://github.com/google-research/t5x.git (to revision 24feab6892a79b3fc465b7b3f2d1c77fc437b67a) to /tmp/pip-install-wh571lzf/t5x_84d8a508d3a944e893250265fbc32f1a
  Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/google-research/t5x.git /tmp/pip-install-wh571lzf/t5x_84d8a508d3a944e893250265fbc32f1a
  Running command git rev-parse -q --verify 'sha^24feab6892a79b3fc465b7b3f2d1c77fc437b67a'
  Running command git fetch -q https://github.com/google-research/t5x.git 24feab6892a79b3fc465b7b3f2d1c77fc437b67a
  Running command git checkout -q 24feab6892a79b3fc465b7b3f2d1c77fc437b67a
  Resolved https://github.com/google-research/t5x.git to commit 24feab6892a79b3fc465b7b3f2d1c77fc437b67a
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting jestimator
  Using cached jestimator-0.3.3-py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Collecting clu
  Using cached clu-0.0.8-py3-none-any.whl (96 kB)
Collecting orbax
  Using cached orbax-0.1.4-py3-none-any.whl (76 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.12 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from flax@ git+https://github.com/google/flax@ccf48a62acafd1f8658d60e21457c4bb57b25b95) (1.22.4)
Requirement already satisfied: jax>=0.4.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from flax@ git+https://github.com/google/flax@ccf48a62acafd1f8658d60e21457c4bb57b25b95) (0.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: msgpack in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from flax@ git+https://github.com/google/flax@ccf48a62acafd1f8658d60e21457c4bb57b25b95) (1.0.5)
Collecting optax
  Downloading optax-0.1.4-py3-none-any.whl (154 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 154.9/154.9 KB 7.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting tensorstore
  Downloading tensorstore-0.1.33-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (8.4 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 8.4/8.4 MB 87.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting rich>=11.1
  Downloading rich-13.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (238 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 238.7/238.7 KB 28.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: typing_extensions>=4.1.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from flax@ git+https://github.com/google/flax@ccf48a62acafd1f8658d60e21457c4bb57b25b95) (4.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML>=5.4.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from flax@ git+https://github.com/google/flax@ccf48a62acafd1f8658d60e21457c4bb57b25b95) (6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: absl-py in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from clu) (1.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: etils[epath] in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from clu) (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wrapt in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from clu) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from clu) (23.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jaxlib in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from clu) (0.4.4+cuda11.cudnn82)
Collecting ml-collections
  Downloading ml_collections-0.1.1.tar.gz (77 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 77.9/77.9 KB 11.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting cached_property
  Downloading cached_property-1.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.6 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib_resources in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from orbax) (5.12.0)
Collecting jax>=0.4.2
  Downloading jax-0.4.6.tar.gz (1.2 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.2/1.2 MB 49.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting clu@ git+https://github.com/google/CommonLoopUtils#egg=clu
  Cloning https://github.com/google/CommonLoopUtils to /tmp/pip-install-wh571lzf/clu_5837e209762c457097ce7de4a98ad6d3
  Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/google/CommonLoopUtils /tmp/pip-install-wh571lzf/clu_5837e209762c457097ce7de4a98ad6d3
  Resolved https://github.com/google/CommonLoopUtils to commit 6dd92f9d8db4b86234c42e302160cf4c2bf163af
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting flax@ git+https://github.com/google/flax#egg=flax
  Cloning https://github.com/google/flax to /tmp/pip-install-wh571lzf/flax_061afe6d94984c2499afac61f22cf5af
  Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/google/flax /tmp/pip-install-wh571lzf/flax_061afe6d94984c2499afac61f22cf5af
  Resolved https://github.com/google/flax to commit 4efd541ded8e31326a5ca3de5955c5274ad3d24c
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting orbax@ git+https://github.com/google/orbax#egg=orbax
  Cloning https://github.com/google/orbax to /tmp/pip-install-wh571lzf/orbax_438ab2b57ec84691be847b96d1af9a44
  Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/google/orbax /tmp/pip-install-wh571lzf/orbax_438ab2b57ec84691be847b96d1af9a44
  Resolved https://github.com/google/orbax to commit 37950426ce0d65ddbd28e29c35f9aebef0ba07e3
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting seqio@ git+https://github.com/google/seqio#egg=seqio
  Cloning https://github.com/google/seqio to /tmp/pip-install-wh571lzf/seqio_9cc1aec2821d45cda70e6a0dcef045db
  Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/google/seqio /tmp/pip-install-wh571lzf/seqio_9cc1aec2821d45cda70e6a0dcef045db
  Resolved https://github.com/google/seqio to commit 99863074f559b38eadc9c5924fab65beb60bc610
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of orbax to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting orbax
  Downloading orbax-0.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (74 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 74.2/74.2 KB 6.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of clu to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting clu
  Downloading clu-0.0.7-py3-none-any.whl (92 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 92.8/92.8 KB 11.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-datasets in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from clu) (4.8.3)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (from clu) (2.11.0)
  Downloading clu-0.0.6-py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 77.8/77.8 KB 11.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading clu-0.0.5-py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 77.5/77.5 KB 9.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading clu-0.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (76 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 76.1/76.1 KB 7.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading clu-0.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (73 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 73.0/73.0 KB 8.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Downloading clu-0.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (68 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 68.8/68.8 KB 9.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of <Python from Requires-Python> to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of jestimator to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting jestimator
  Downloading jestimator-0.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of clu to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: This is taking longer than usual. You might need to provide the dependency resolver with stricter constraints to reduce runtime. See https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/backtracking for guidance. If you want to abort this run, press Ctrl + C.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of flax to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
ERROR: Cannot install clu==0.0.2, flax 0.6.8 (from git+https://github.com/google/flax@ccf48a62acafd1f8658d60e21457c4bb57b25b95), jestimator==0.3.2 and t5x==0.0.0 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    The user requested flax 0.6.8 (from git+https://github.com/google/flax@ccf48a62acafd1f8658d60e21457c4bb57b25b95)
    jestimator 0.3.2 depends on flax
    clu 0.0.2 depends on flax
    t5x 0.0.0 depends on flax 0.6.8 (from git+https://github.com/google/flax#egg=flax)

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts
```

What I don't understand about this error message is that I request `flax` version `0.6.8` and that `t5X` depends on that same version `0.6.8` but `pip` is unable to resolve this.

I'm certain there must be a resolution because the `requirements.txt` that I am using with these specific pinned versions is the output from `pip freeze > requirements.txt` from the virtual environment from a colleague.